# After WooCommerce-Update fucntion not working anymore

Tags: updates, customization

I got a problem and I am realy dying on this right now.
I did the WooCommerce Update up to the major 3 version and straight to 3.0.2.

After completet, updated the database. So far so good.

My problem now is, that a function I wrote seems to work no longer. Its like this:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals','calc_ferienspiele_discount' );
function calc_ferienspiele_discount( $cart_object ) {
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$x=0;
$custom_price = 140; // This will be your custome price
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    $target_product_id=$value['data']->get_sku();
    for ($_i = 1; $_i <= $value['quantity']; $_i++) {
        $x++;
        if ( $value['data']->get_sku() == $target_product_id ) {
            if ($x>1) {
                $value['data']->set_price = $custom_price;
                echo $value['data']->get_sku();
                echo 'This works and get displayed';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I now its maybe a little sloppy but what it did is, it checked, if there are several items with the same SKU. If so, it counted up. When there is more than 1 item of that specific SKU, the following cost less. So if the item is 3 times in the cart the first would be 100$, and the other two like 80$.

I can jump into the last `if` where the new price is set (tested that with an `echo`), but the new price wont be set. I assume something changed from major version 2 to 3 and I cant figure it out whats wrong here. spent hours on finding it...

U guys have any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it. With the update of WooCommerce, which I assumed, the syntax of the set price did change. Function now looks like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calc_ferienspiele_discount' );
function calc_ferienspiele_discount( $cart_object ) {
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$x=0;
$custom_price = 140; // This will be your custome price
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    $target_product_id=$value['data']->get_sku();
    for ($_i = 1; $_i <= $value['quantity']; $_i++) {
        $x++;
        if ( $target_product_id=='01010101' ) {
            if ($x>1) {
                $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
                echo 'This works and get displayed';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```